# Spread values not being recognized in Create method

Tags: typescript, deno

Deno has sessionStorage globally available, which is what I'm using as my in-memory database.

I'm working on a method that creates a new museum in sessionStorage. However, the problem is that my create method only works when my Museum type does *not* extend Record.

Here are my types:

```
// I want my Museum type to extend the Record type for the extra type safety
interface Museum extends Record<string, unknown> {
  id: string
  name: string
  description: string
  location: {
    lat: number
    lng: number
  }
  createdAt: Date
  updatedAt?: Date
}

// I'm testing two different NewMuseum types
type NewMuseum = Omit<Museum, "id" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt">
// type NewMuseum = Partial<Museum>
```

Here is my class:

```
export class Repository {
  
  async getList(): Promise<Museum[]> {
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('museums') || '[]') as Museum[]
  }

  async create(museum: NewMuseum): Promise<Museum> {
    const museumList = await this.getList()
    const newMuseum = {
      id: crypto.randomUUID(),
      ...museum,
      createdAt: new Date(),
    }
    museumList.push(newMuseum)
    sessionStorage.setItem('museums', JSON.stringify(museumList))
    
    return newMuseum
  }
}
```

When I go to spread the values of the new museum the linter catches an error on `newMuseum` on the `museumList.push(newMuseum)` line.

```
Argument of type '{ createdAt: Date; id: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Museum'.deno-ts(2345)
```

newMuseum isn't recognizing the values I'm spreading in it. Instead, newMuseum should look like this:

```
const newMuseum: {
    createdAt: Date;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    location: {
        lat: number;
        lng: number;
    };
    id: string;
}
```

How do I get newMuseum to recognize the spread values? Should I be attempting to fix the issue with the Partial utility type instead of Omit?

Comment: just remove `extends Record<string, unknown>`. I don't see it serving any purpose here. What do you mean with "for the extra type safety" ?

Answer (score 0):

Casting the newMuseum object as Museum is what did the trick. Here is the updated solution:

```
export class Repository {
  
  async getList(): Promise<Museum[]> {
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('museums') || '[]') as Museum[]
  }

  async create(museum: NewMuseum): Promise<Museum> {
    const museumList = await this.getList()
    const newMuseum = {
      ...museum,
      id: crypto.randomUUID(),
      createdAt: new Date(),
    } as Museum
    museumList.push(newMuseum)
    sessionStorage.setItem('museums', JSON.stringify(museumList))
    
    return newMuseum
  }
}
```

Typescript doesn't really know the type of the spread operator so it assumes it's incompatible. as Museum tells the typescript typechecker "no worries, I'm sure this is right."

Shoutout to the Deno Discord for the help!

Comment: If you don't want `...museum` to override `id` then I suggest placing `id: crypto.randomUUID()` after it; others a user could cast a `Museum` as a `NewMuseum` or otherwise send an object in with an `id` property and it would overwrite your random one.

Comment: @mfulton26 great tip, updated the solution. Thank you!

Comment: @TobiasS. it's not saying that TS doesn't know how to handle the spread operator, it's saying that in this instance, ts doesn't know the type of the object specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The values you are expecting to be recognized in your spread operation are not there because the `NewMuseum` doesn't contain them. `Omit` is causing the set of keys to be changed:

```
type NewMuseum = Omit<Museum, "id" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt">;
```

resolves to

```
type NewMuseum = {
    [x: string]: unknown;
    [x: number]: unknown;
}
```

and not to

```
interface NewMuseum extends Record<string, unknown> {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  location: {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
  };
}
```

As such, long before you attempt to spread a `NewMuseum` the type information for those keys is already lost.

You might consider composing your types rather computing types via utilities like `Omit`.

e.g.

```
type MuseumData = Record<string, unknown> & {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  location: {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
  };
};

type MuseumMetadata = {
  id: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
};

type Museum = MuseumData & MuseumMetadata;

type NewMuseum = MuseumData;
```